# Reading from a communications resource

Tags: c, readfile, device, createfile

I want to read some data from a device connected to a COM port.

- `HANDLE handle =`[`CreateFileW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(L"\\\\.\\COM3", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);`

  gives me a valid `HANDLE` which is then configured via `GetCommState` and `SetCommState`.
- `OVERLAPPED ol = {0};`

  `char buffer[1024];`

  `ol.Offset = 0;`

  `ol.OffsetHigh = 0;`

  [`ReadFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365468%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)`(handle, buffer, 1, &ol, NULL);`

  The problem is, that this call doesn't succeed and `GetLastError()` returns 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

What could I try to be able to read from the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReadFileEx documentation states that

> The ReadFileEx function ignores the OVERLAPPED structure's hEvent
>   member. An application is free to use that member for its own purposes
>   in the context of a ReadFileEx call. ReadFileEx signals completion of
>   its read operation by calling, or queuing a call to, the completion
>   routine pointed to by lpCompletionRoutine, so it does not need an
>   event handle.

So although it also says that the completion routine is optional, it's probably needed. Also note the community comment at the bottom of the page you linked to - MS may have fixed that crash by considering a NULL lpCompletionRoutine an error. However, I have not tested it to verify.

If you are not using a completion routine you can use the normal ReadFile for your overlapped operation.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a bug in MS implementation of `ReadFileEx`. Despite the documentation clearly stating that one should not reply entirely on the `BOOL` return result and that one should also check `GetLastError()` the implementation fails to clear any pre-existing error.  Add a `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS)` before calling `ReadFileEx()`.